# Refactor on_press into class rule

Tags: python, kivy

In my RootWidget I have a label and two buttons. I want to dynamically change the text of the label whenever one of the buttons is clicked.

Here's a minimal working example of how I do it at the moment.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App

w = Builder.load_string('''
<RootWidget>:
    id: root_widget

    Label:
        id: label
        text: 'Push a button'
    Button:
        text: '1'
        on_press: label.text = self.text
    Button:
        text: '2'
        on_press: label.text = self.text
''')

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Obviously I want to refactor the line `on_press: label.text = self.text`. My first tries ended in

```
<RootWidget>:
    id: root_widget

    Label:
        id: label
        text: 'Push a button'
    MyButton:
        text: '1'
    MyButton:
        text: '2'

<MyButton>:
    on_press: label.text = self.text
```

But obviously the `MyButton`-class doesn't know the property `label` of the `RootWidget`-class. And class rules inside class rules is also not allowed.

Is there a way of accomplishing binding the `on_press`-action dynamically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the `Label` like this:

```
<MyButton@Button>:
    on_press: self.parent.ids.label.text = self.text
<RootWidget>:
    id: root_widget

    Label:
        id: label
        text: 'Push a button'
    MyButton:
        text: '1'
    MyButton:
        text: '2'
```

Answer (score 2):

It's quite simple actually, because through kv you can access parent of a widget/rule easily with `self.parent`, so your code would look like:

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.app import App

w = Builder.load_string('''
<RootWidget>:
    id: root_widget

    Label:
        id: label
        text: 'Push a button'
    But:
        text: '1'
    But:
        text: '2'
<But>:
    on_press: self.parent.label.text = self.text
''')

class RootWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: Funny, I think it's never happened to me until now. I skip answering on questions with comments/answers. :D

Comment: This one was low-hanging fruit :)